# ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class on OPENSHIFT Tomcat 7 ( Jboss EWS)

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, jboss, openshift

I recently wished to deploy my java web application project to openshift using the Tomcat 7( Jboss EWS). I opted to use the eclipse openshift plugin and cloned the project and made changes ; however after publishing the app, my index pages loads just fine except when i wish to log in to the application it throws an exception (500 server side ) stating the servlet concerned was not instatiated.

I have tried several methods ,using different cartridges however the problem still persist, i have not been able to find a solution.

I have tried changing the source target to my WEB-INF/classes folder i created feeling maybe it is not finding the classes. I am not certain as to why it cant find my classes.

If anyone has encountered this before , kindly assist, i could have the structuring all wrong.

Here is the log :

exception

```
  javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class com.asza.controllers.Login
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:683)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

                root cause
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.asza.controllers.Login
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:683)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say what exactly goes wrong for you. To be of an optimal help I'd ask you to provide me your source so that I can try it if that's possible.
Furthermore I see the following steps that you can try:

- When pushing to openshift a maven build is triggered. The output of that build should tell you how your classes (especially what folder) are packaged. Is it telling you that /classes is packaged?
- Did you try to deploy to a local server? If that works then we know that your application is all fine and you face an openshift specific issue.

Cheers
André

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried changing the source target to my `WEB-INF/classes` folder i created feeling maybe it is not finding the classes. I am not certain as to why it cant find my classes.

Clean, rebuild, redeploy.

`WEB-INF/classes` should have all required classes, other classes should be in dependencies classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for timely responses, they were much help. 
However i have finally resolved the issue and i will explain thus forth ;

The main problem initially was the class version error as i am currently using Oracle JDK 8 to compile and build the entire application.
Thus i had to downgrade and opted to use JDK 7 instead, that is compatible with the openshift tomcat jboss ews cartridge i was using. (The cartridge uses jdk 7 ).

However , other problems still persisted ; which are :

1. Openshift tomcat cartridge would not find my scripts and files (html,jsp,servlets) ; upon attempting to access a servlet the server would return 404 Error (Not found ) ; it would not see the servlets. ( oddly!)

To solve this, for anyone else who may have encountered a similar problem.

After having built your war file, (of which in my case i was using ubuntu and was cloning the project and deleted the pom and src folders and would place the war file directly in the webapps folder);

Before pushing to openshift repository i had to copy my web.xml and pasted the content in the openshift project ( previously cloned ) .config/ folder in the web.xml of that project.

NB: Do not delete the projects ( openshift cloned ) web.xml ; rather copy ur servlet mappings and so forth so that openshifts tomcat can find them; that solves the ( 404 Not found error) .

Lastly, for some reason ; tomcat was not unpacking the war file content upon deploy, thus you have to manually edit the ./config/config file and change the value of 
"unpackWar=false " to true, that way ; the server will unpack your files automatically.

These solutions worked for me and all is well now; however, one could also place the servelt mappings in the class annotations if you wish to avoid editing openshifts web.xml....

Do not forget to commit and push all your changess.